# Seeing the changes in Android studio live

Tags: java, android

I use android studio, but I don't want to press f5 and wait every time, I want to see that change immediately on the phone as soon as there is any change, just like when using xamarin, is there a solution or is it impossible.I searched but found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the xamarin's functionality you're referring to but in Android Studio you can use the live edit functionality that allows you to see immediately the changes in the android device (emulator/phone).

To enabled it, open Android Studio's settings, `Editor` -> `Live edit` and select `Push Edits automatically`

Tested on Android Studio Iguana